# How to validate that user specified correct Date in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

Is there any simple way to client (and server) side validate Date ?

My idea is to have 3 input fields for day, month and year. I'm using anotated model and AJAX validation scripts to client side validate the data. How can I do that with date ?

I can set something like day must be from Range<1, 31> but still, if the month is february then value 31 is invalid...

Comment: Why don't you use a javascript datepicker? like the jquery's one?

Comment: That seems to be reasonable suggestion. I spent few last hours looking for some that would satisfy all my needs(jQuery one is not the case)...

Comment: And what are your needs?

Comment: @bAN jQuery is great except I would prefer some picker that consist of 3 fields: for day, month and year. Sometimes users do not like to bother with UI drop down but they rather write it. In such case formating is never clear to user - is it delimited by `/` or space ? Or even '\'? And 3 fields with labels are clear to understand and so usable even when javascript is off.

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.asp.net/p/1500029/3546376.aspx and http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/17816-Javascript-date-validation.aspx.... may help u i hope. all the best

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bAN - the most user friendly way is to use a datepicker. Users with javascript disabled will have to write the dates manually into the textbox. You can also detect disabled javascript and do a fallback to a version without the datepicker in that case.

If you really want 3 input fields, you have a few options though. You need 3 properties on your model `int day; int month; int year;`. When you receive the data from the client, you will have to do the validation manually by trying to create a `DateTime` object. It will throw an exception if you specify an incorrect format:

```
try
{
    var date = new DateTime(model.Year, model.Month, model.Day);
    ...
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(...);
}
```

As a more pleasant user experience you can have 3 dropdowns instead. You can change the number of days depending on which month is selected and/or run validation at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

A [custom model binder](http://www.longcloudtech.com/Blogs/Yankiwi/post/2010/04/21/Updating-Scott-Hanselmane28099s-DateTime-Custom-Model-Binder-%28DateAndTimeModelBinder%29.aspx) seems like a good solution for this.